# How to create XConnect service in single instance from Sitecore XP1 Scaled installtion package

Tags: xdb, xconnect, scaling

we are setting up QA instance and following Sitecore Vertical scaling guide from sitecore doc (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/scale-vertically.html).

We are following Dedicated Content Delivery instance topology in which we will need to create one CD,One CM and One XConnect.

**Challenge on XConnect**: As sitecore has broken down whole XConnect service into multiple service instances,How can i create single instace for xConnect by using XP1 Scaled Script?

For Example:all xConnect and xDB roles (i.e. Collection, Collection Search, Marketing Automation, Marketing Automation Reporting, and ReferenceData) can be installed in a single instance(https://github.com/raseniero/Sitecore-v901-XP1-Scaled-Installation)

Thanks & regards,
Bansidhar

Comment: Use the XP0 variant for xConnect. You will get all services under a single web site.

Comment: Thank you @Jrap.Do i need to update xp1-cm.json for CM instance as i see few variation after running xp1-cm.json file i mean processing.task database is not created in sql.

Comment: If you want CM server to do essentially everything, then also use XP0 in standalone configuration for CM server. This will give you your processing databases and act as a processing server.

Comment: Thanks Jrap.We are having another issue related to trusting of certificate in UAT server(we are using valid ssl certificate) still we are facing problem on experience analytics